# Python 3.6 tkinter image "pyimage20" doesn't exist

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter

Trying to add a button with background image on the main class of a multiple frame GUI. Works well when ran on a separate class on a separate window but gives: **_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage20" doesn't exist** error when ran in the main class.

```
button_pady = 5

self.homebutton_image = tki.PhotoImage(file="Images/Resized/homebutton.png")

self.homebutton = tki.Button(self, image=self.homebutton_image, compound=BOTTOM)

self.homebutton.image = self.homebutton_image

self.homebutton.pack(side=TOP, pady=button_pady)
```

Main class has been defined such as:

```
class MainClass(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Any idea why this occurs?
Have looked at a lot of other questions but nothing helped so far.
When self is removed so the following line looks like it works well:

```
self.homebutton = tki.Button(image=self.homebutton_image, compound=BOTTOM)
```

Which i think it means that there is an issue with the class.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use several `Tk()` instances in your program?

Comment: No only once on the main class. Other classes are defined as:            
class ChildClass1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

Comment: Can you try `tki.PhotoImage(file="Images/Resized/homebutton.png", master=self)` to define the image?

Comment: That works very well. Thank you very much. Tried to understand this issue for so many days! Would you be able to explain it to me?

Comment: I think that the default master (the one used when no master is given at the widget creation) is not `self`. Therefore the Button and the PhotoImage don't have the same master and this triggers the error. Usually, this issue is caused by the existence of several `Tk` instances, but I cannot tell the exact reason in your case because I don't have enough code.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I am quite new to python so I guess I didn't understand your first question. I am using multiple frames so that must be causing the issue.

Comment: No, having multiple frames is not an issue, I was really talking about `Tk()` instances. I usually encounter the same problem as you when testing code in a Ipython qtconsole because the default master is not the `Tk()` instance I create.